# Is there any way to obtain the index of a particular token in a doc rather than looping?

Tags: spacy-3

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_web_core_sm')
doc = nlp("I love spacy. Spacy is so cool.")

for token in doc:
   print(token)
```

This prints every token in a new line. But if I want "cool" token separately, I should know the index of that token right!! What can I do about that?

Ex: If there are 1000 words in the doc, I want a particular word "simulate" as a separate token but I don't know the position of that token in that doc. Rather than looping around those 1000 words, Is there any way to directly obtain the index of "simulate"?

Answer (score 0):

`token.i` has the token index of a token in the document. `token.idx` has the character index.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
doc = nlp("I like cheese")

assert doc[2].text == "cheese"
assert doc[2].i == 2
assert doc[2].idx == 7
```

Comment: My question is I don't know the index of that particular token. But you are specifying the index in your answer. Let's say there is a doc of 1 million words. You have to find out the index of a token in that whole doc. The only thing you know is the text of a token. So what I'm asking is can't we just give token text as an argument to some built-in method in spacy and get the token index in that doc?

Comment: spaCy does not pre-emptively index tokens in the document by their text, no. When you say "built-in method" I guess the Matcher can kind of do that, but it's still iterating over the tokens internally.

Comment: Iterating over words in the Doc is extremely fast, I can't imagine doing it once for lookup being a bottleneck in any normal situation.